# .net core generic host runs twice,when deployed to google cloud app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
            {
                configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                configHost.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "PREFIX_");
                configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
            {
                configApp.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, reloadOnChange: true);
                configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "PREFIX_");
                configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddScoped(typeof(IAppLogger<>), 

                services.AddHostedService<HostedPaymentService>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
            {
                configLogging.AddConsole();
                configLogging.AddDebug();
            })
            .UseConsoleLifetime()
            .Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Here is the hosted service start method, is there something wrong in the below code?

```
internal class HostedPaymentService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            var dueDateTime = new DateTime(currentDateTime.Year, currentDateTime.Month, currentDateTime.Day, _options.ExecutionHour, _options.ExecutionMinute, 0);
            var dueTimeDiffFromCurrentTime = dueDateTime < currentDateTime ? dueDateTime.AddDays(1) - currentDateTime : dueDateTime - currentDateTime;

            _logger.LogInformation($"Service has started at {DateTime.Now} ");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Job will be triggered at {dueDateTime.ToShortTimeString()}");

            _timer = new Timer(workToBeDone =>
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Invoked at {DateTime.Now}");
                    _recurringPaymentService.Process();
                }, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(dueTimeDiffFromCurrentTime.TotalSeconds), TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

---

Code inside Start method is executed twice when deployed to GCP app engine.
Initially i used Quartz then i used TimedHostedService but problem presists.
Everything is working fine in local environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy Node.js on Google app engine, running twice issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665498/deploy-node-js-on-google-app-engine-running-twice-issue)